# cin.getline is skipping one line of input and taking the next

Tags: c++, cin, getline

Why does cin.getline start working for the second line on the body input but break on the first?

Example Program run:

```
Enter name: Will
Enter body: hello world
hello again <= It accepts this one



 char* name = new char[100];
 char* body = new char[500];

 std::cout << "Enter name: ";
 std::cin.clear();
 std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
 std::cin.getline(name, 100);

 std::cout << "Enter body: ";
 std::cin.clear();
 std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
 std::cin.getline(body, 500');
 std::cin >> body;
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're ignoring the first line with the cin.ignore statement.

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

That will ignore a whole line.

Remove that and you'll get what you want.

You may also want to flush the cout stream to assure your output prints to the screen right away. Add a `cout.flush();` before your getline.

Comment: I removed both of them and it was the same except it skipped the name input

Comment: @Will03uk: I added a bit to my answer. You may want to add a flush.

Comment: I made the same assertion about flush aq couple of weeks ago, but @anon pointed out that the std::cin is tied to std::cout forcing an automatic flush before std::cin does a read: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/tie/

Answer (score 2):

As JoshD says, but additionally, you can save a lot of work & pain by using `std::string` and `std::getline` from the `<string>` header.

Like ...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    std::string name;
    cout << "Enter name: ";  getline( cin, name );
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

– Alf